# How to have a Spring dynamic proxy with 2 interfaces?

Tags: java, spring, proxy, dynamic-proxy

I have an object that is injected into my class by Spring ([JdbcCursorItemReader](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JdbcCursorItemReader.html) if you care).

It implements 5 interfaces, two of which I care about (ItemReader, ItemStream). If I code my class to one or the other, the spring dynamic proxy gets properly injected and I can call methods on it

```
private ItemReader blah;
public void setItemReader( blah ) { this.blah = blah };
```

Cool, that works as expected. I can also cast it to an ItemStream if I want to do something based on the ItemStream Interface:

```
((ItemStream))blah.close();
```

Cool, that lets me access methods of both classes. However, I am not a fan of casting, and know where has to be a better Spring Magic way to do it. The way I thought of was to make an Interface that combines both:

```
public interface IStreamingItemReader<T> extends ItemReader<T>, ItemStream {
}
```

This lets my code use both... but the proxy injection predictably fails.

> Failed to convert property value of
>   type [$Proxy0 implementing
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean,org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader,org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStream,org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedObject,org.springframework.aop.framework.AopInfrastructureBean,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised]
>   to required type
>   [blah.IStreamingItemReader] for
>   property 'itemReader'; nested
>   exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Cannot convert value of type [$Proxy0
>   implementing
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean,org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader,org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStream,org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedObject,org.springframework.aop.framework.AopInfrastructureBean,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised]
>   to required type
>   [blah.IStreamingItemReader] for
>   property 'itemReader': no matching
>   editors or conversion strategy found

The part that got my eye was
**no matching editors or conversion strategy found**

Is there a way to teach Spring when it sees a **JdbcCursorItemReader**, to make a proxy of a **IStreamingItemReader**?

I realize I could fix this with CGLib and class based proxies... but if I could keep this as a dynamic interface proxy, I would be happier...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1

```
private ItemReader blah;
private ItemStream blubb;
public void setItemReader( blah ) { this.blah = blah };
public void setItemStream( blubb ) { this.blubb = blubb };
```

Option 2

```
class ItemAccessor {
 private ItemReader reader;
 private ItemStream stream;
 // Setter & co ...
}
```

Then:

```
private ItemAccessor accessor;

accessor.getReader().read();
accessor.getStream().stream();
```

Answer (score 3):

Easy way: if possible, make your implementing class implement your union interface instead of the two separate interfaces.

Less clear way, but does not introduce addtional classes (needs generics):

```
public interface A { }

public interface B { }

public class C implements A, B { }

public class D {
    private A a;
    private B b;

    public <T extends A & B> void setObject(T o) {
        this.a = o;
        this.b = o;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        D d = new D();
        d.setObject(new C());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another option with generics (mostly as a theoretical exercise), doesn't require duplicated fields, but requires a holder object:

```
class ReaderStreamHolder<T extends ItemReader & ItemStream> {
    private final T target;
    public ReaderStreamHolder(T target) {
        this.target = target;
    }
    public T get() {
        return target;
    }
}
```

.

```
private ReaderStreamHolder<?> blah; 
public <T extends ItemReader & ItemStream> void setItemReader(T target) { 
    this.blah = new ReaderStreamHolder<T>(target)
};
```

.

```
blah.get().close();
```